# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}{\sqrt{2}x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos \left(2x\right)}}{\sqrt{2}x}\right)$

= $\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2\sin\left(x\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2}x}\right)$

= $\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\sin x}{\sqrt{2}x}\right)$

= $\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\dfrac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}\right)$ = 1

But the actual answer turns out to be (limit does not exist). How does that happen?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{\sin^2 x} = | \sin x|$, hence for $x < 0$ it is $- \sin x$. So the right limit is 1, but the left limit is -1.

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$\sqrt{\sin^2(x)}=|\sin(x)|\sim|x|$$
so your limit is 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x|}{x}$$
and it doesn't exist!

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense.$\sqrt{\sin \left(x\right)}$ = sinx not |x| although it might be the approximation. So why do we discard the whole sinx instead take it as |x| and say the limit does not exist. (Limit is so fishy x( )

Comment: I didn't say that $\sqrt{\sin^2x}=|x|$ but asymptotically equal and never mind if you don't know this you can just replace $\sqrt{\sin^2x}$ by $|\sin x|$ to see that the limit doesn't exist.